# prove $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} ({\frac{x_1+x_{n+1}}{x_n}})^n \geq e$

Tags: real-analysis

$x_n>0$, show that $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} ({\frac{x_1+x_{n+1}}{x_n}})^n \geq e$.

Don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: Where is $n$ goes?

Comment: Sorry, n goes to infinity

Comment: Do you mean the limit of $\frac{x_n+x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ as $n\to\infty$? As stated, I’m pretty sure your conjecture is wrong.

Comment: You want this result for every sequence $x_n$? Or do you have a specific one in mind?

Comment: Contrary to what people might suspect, this is a true statement.

Comment: @CalvinKhor I think it's for every sequence.

Answer (score 3):

This is true for every sequence. The solution is from *Coffee Time in Memphis* by Bollobas.

By dividing the whole sequence by $x_1$, there is no harm in assuming $x_1 = 1$. Assuming that the conclusion is false, there exists $0<c<1$ such that LHS is strictly less that $e^c$. This implies that for sufficiently large $n$, say for $n\geq N$, we have
$$
\frac{1+x_{n+1}}{x_n} < 1+\frac{c}{n}
$$
since otherwise, by passing to the subsequence such that the inequality right above does not hold, we have that
$$
\text{limsup} \left(\frac{1+x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right)^n \geq (1+c/n)^n \geq e^c
$$

Then, by induction on $k$, the book claims that we can show that
$$
x_{N+k} < x_N\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}\left(1+\frac{c}{N+i}\right) - k
$$
impliying
$$
x_{N+k} \leq x_N \text{exp}\left(\sum_{i=0}^k \frac{c}{N+i}\right)-k \approx x_N (N+k)^c - k
$$
which contradicts $x_{N+k}>0$ as the RHS goes to negative as $k\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks! This is good! I am going to find the book Coffee Time in Memphis by Bollobas.